# If I drop a table and the table doesn't exist, I get an error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to drop a table and make a new one.  If I drop the table and the table doesn't exist, I get an error

How can I check if the table exists?

I'm working on Oracle 11g

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Getting an error isn't the end of the world - you can just handle the error with an exception handler if the table doesn't exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle: If Table Exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799128/oracle-if-table-exists)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
DECLARE v_exist PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_exist
FROM user_tables
WHERE table_name = 'YOURTABLEHERE';

IF v_exist = 1 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE YOURTABLEHERE';
END IF;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE
  eTABLE_OR_VIEW_DOES_NOT_EXIST  EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(eTABLE_OR_VIEW_DOES_NOT_EXIST, -942);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE SCHEMA.WHATEVER';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN eTABLE_OR_VIEW_DOES_NOT_EXIST THEN
    NULL;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
select count(*) from user_tables 
where table_name= :table name
```

or

```
select count(*) from dba_tables
where owner = :table owner
and table_name = :table name
```

or a heavy-handed alternative:

```
begin execute immediate 'drop table table_name'; 
exception when others then null; 
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the following procedure to take care of this:

```
create or replace procedure drop_table_if_exists ( p_table_name varchar2 )
is
  it_exist number;
begin
  select count(*) 
     into it_exists
     from user_tables
     where table_name = p_table_name
  ;
  if it_exists >= 1 then
    execute immediate 'drop table '||p_table_name;
  end if;
end;
/

exec drop_table_if_exists ( 'TABLE_TO_DROP' );
```