# How to check if a table exist in Oracle?

Tags: oracle9i

In Sql I check if a table exist with this code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM SYSOBJECTS  
     WHERE NAME = 'Plane')
   CREATE TABLE Plane(Flight int)
```

How to do this check if a table not exist then i create it in Oracle because it throws exception if i try to create already existing table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle: If Table Exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799128/oracle-if-table-exists)

Answer (score 2):

you can check the data dictionary for that table

```
select table_name from user_tables where table_name='MYTABLE';
```

Answer (score 1):

CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    (create_definition,...)
    [table_options]
    [partition_options]