# How do you use SQL to see whether a table exists or not?

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server: Check if table exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/sql-server-check-if-table-exists)
>   [Oracle: If Table Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799128/oracle-if-table-exists)

I'm trying to create a table and insert some values, but before I do I must make sure that the table doesn't already exist. How do you check for this?

Comment: which language , as in mysql you can use if exists

Comment: I'm currently using Oracle right now. It seems that all the answers assumed I was using SQL Server since I forgot to mention it in there....

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  With Oracle there is rarely a need to create tables on the fly (unlike certain other flavours of DBMS).

Answer (score 1):

You can try simply SELECTing from it and capturing the error, otherwise you will need to write DB specific SQL to query their respective metadata tables and look there.

Answer (score 0):

IF MySQL:

```
select count(*) from my_tables where table_name='table_1'; 
If count>0 then  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server...Query sysobjects:

```
select * from sysobjects where xtype='U' and name ='tablename'
```

Comment: Or for SQL Server **2005** and newer - even better - query `sys.tables`: `if exists (select * from sys.tables where Name = 'tablename') .....`

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use the CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS construct and run it before your INSERT query. This will create the table if it doesn't exist and will do nothing if the table is there.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable (
    ....
)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/create-table.html

Comment: Do you know what it's like for Oracle instead of SQL Server?

Comment: This seems to be the same for oracle, but I'm not 100%. Looking at their docs, this looks to be the same:

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/create-table.html

Comment: that documentation is for MySQL see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/

Answer (score 0):

This simple query gives you details about the particular table which are created by users in oracle. Try it.

```
 select * from user_tables where table_name = 'tablename';
```

Comment: Don't forget that table names are in upper case by default.

Comment: here tablenane is generic name for tables. tablename is not a particular table.

Comment: I understand that, but the OP might not be aware of that.