# Drop table if it exists

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following PL/SQL:

```
declare
    i_cnt number;
begin
    select count(1) into i_cnt 
      from dba_tables 
     where table_name = upper('foo') 
       and owner = upper('bar'); 

if i_cnt > 0 then 
    drop table foo; -- <--- error this line
end if;
end;
```

From which I get this error.

```
ORA-06550: line 6, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DROP" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
```

How can I drop a table in a procedure?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799128/oracle-if-table-exists/1801453

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't directly execute DDL statements from a PL/SQL block - you'll have to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE instead:

```
declare
  i_cnt number;
begin
  select count(1) into i_cnt 
  from dba_tables where table_name=upper('foo') and owner=upper('bar'); 
  if i_cnt > 0 then 
    execute immediate 'drop table foo'; 
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: is it possible to combine the `select` and `if` statement into one line? i need to do this for many tables so i want to save some typing.

Comment: You say you need to do this for many tables.  Can you characterize the list of tables based on criteria against DBA_TABLES?  In other words, can you write a query against DBA_TABLES and specify an appropriate WHERE clause that would list all the tables you want to drop?  If so, you can write a cursor loop and do the execute immediate drop in the loop, specifying bind variable, and loop throug to drop all the tables you want to drop.

Comment: @Mark J. Bobak, good idea! i'm already doing it that way for the grants. couldn't know why didn't do that for the tables and sequences. :)