# Drop a table in a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle: If Table Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799128/oracle-if-table-exists)
>   [Drop table if it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838558/drop-table-if-it-exists)

I'm trying to create this procedure but I get an error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_VEXISTABLA(NOMBRE IN VARCHAR2)
IS
CANTIDAD NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CANTIDAD FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = NOMBRE;
IF (CANTIDAD >0) THEN
    DROP TABLE NOMBRE;
END IF;
END;
```

The error is:

> Error(8,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma    raise return select update while with       <<    continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback    savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge.

Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which tool do you use to run this?

Comment: Oracle sql developer Version 3.2.20.09

Comment: It's not allowed to use DDL statements (`DROP TABLE NOMBRE;` in this case ) inside a PL/SQL block. To execute a DDL statement inside a PL/SQL block you would have to use dynamic SQL: `execute immediate 'DROP TABLE NOMBRE';` for instance.

Comment: You should be aware that by querying ALL_OBJECTS you might find an object that is neither a table nor in your own schema. If you only want to query for tables in your own schema then use USER_TABLES. Also, if TABLE_LOCK is "DISABLED" or DROPPED is "YES" then the drop will fail.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you'd need to change your procedure to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_VEXISTABLA(NOMBRE IN VARCHAR2)
IS
CANTIDAD NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CANTIDAD FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = NOMBRE;
IF (CANTIDAD >0) THEN
    execute immediate 'DROP TABLE ' || NOMBRE;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: DazzaL@I'm using same stored procedure and getting error BEGIN procedure SP_VEXISTABLA('xyz'); END;

      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PROCEDURE" when expecting one of the
following:
( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
raise return select update while with <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
The symbol "PROCEDURE" was ignored.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot DROP tables in procedure using the DROP command. You need to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to run DDL commands in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 2):

It will not allow you use directly DDL statament inside the PLSQL Procedure.
You need to use `Execute Immediate` statement in order to execute the DDL.

Use the code below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_VEXISTABLA(Table_nameIN VARCHAR2)
IS
CANTIDAD integer;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CANTIDAD FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = Table_name;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CANTIDAD);
   IF (CANTIDAD >0) THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Table_name);
      execute immediate 'DROP TABLE ' || Table_name;
   END IF;
END;
```