# Create or replace table in Oracle pl/sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I need a script which creates table or if it already exist drops it, and when recreates table. After some research I have found out that `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE` in pl/sql doesn't exist. So I come up with this script :

```
DECLARE
   does_not_exist   EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (does_not_exist, -942);
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE foobar';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN does_not_exist
   THEN
      NULL;
END;
/ 

CREATE TABLE foobar (c1 INT);
```

Is there any proper way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Based on what you are attempting, maybe temporary tables would be useful.

Comment: nope, i need to use table, not temporary table. But thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: i never understood this thing. just drop the table - if it dosent exists then no harm done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a global [temporary table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#i1006400) would seem to be a better option.  However, if you insist on dropping and re-adding tables at runtime you could query one of the _TABLES views (i.e. USER_TABLES, DBA_TABLES, ALL_TABLES) to determine if the table exists, drop it if it does, then create it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO nCount
  FROM USER_TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FOOBAR';

IF nCount <> 0 THEN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE FOOBAR';
END IF;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE FOOBAR(...)';
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: @Ben - beat me by one minute!

Answer (score 9):

You really shouldn't be doing this in PL/SQL, tables created at runtime would be indicative of a flaw in your data model. If you're really convinced you absolutely have to do this then investigate [temporary tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables003.htm#ADMIN11633) first. Personally, I'd reassess whether it's necessary at all.

You seem to be going for the [EAFP as opposed to LBYL](http://oranlooney.com/lbyl-vs-eafp/) approach, which is described in a few answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799128/oracle-if-table-exists). I would argue that this is unnecessary. A table is a fairly static beast, you can use the system view [USER_TABLES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_5480.htm#REFRN26286) to determine whether it exists before dropping it.

```
declare

   l_ct number;

begin

   -- Determine if the table exists.
   select count(*) into l_ct
     from user_tables
    where table_name = 'THE_TABLE';

   -- Drop the table if it exists.
   if l_ct = 1 then
      execute immediate 'drop table the_table';
   end if;

   -- Create the new table it either didn-t exist or
   -- has been dropped so any exceptions are exceptional.
   execute immediate 'create table the_table ( ... )';

end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, i know, that it is bad approach to recreate tables at runtime, but i have to do task given to me.