# How to create a table using SQL in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I'm trying to create a simple table but it's giving me an error says:

> Error starting at line 1 in command:
>   DROP TABLE deleted_employees
>   Error report:
>   SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
>
> Error starting at line 2 in command:
>   CREATE TABLE deleted_employees
>   Error at Command Line:2 Column:30
>   Error report:
>   SQL Error: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
>   00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"
>
> Error starting at line 3 in command:
>   (
>    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(6,0),
>     FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
>     LAST_NAME   VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
>     EMAIL       VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
>     PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) ,
>     HIRE_DATE DATE ,
>     JOBE_ID VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
>    SALARY NUMBER(8,2),
>    COMMISSION_ID NUMBER(2,2),
>    MANAGER_ID NUMBER(6,0),
>     DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4,0)
>    )
>
> Error at Command Line:4 Column:2
>   Error report:
>   SQL Error: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
>   00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"

Script:

```
DROP TABLE deleted_employees;
CREATE TABLE deleted_employees; 
(
 EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(6,0),
 FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
 LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
 EMAIL VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
 PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) , 
 HIRE_DATE DATE , 
 JOB_ID VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
 SALARY NUMBER(8,2),
 COMMISSION_ID NUMBER(2,2),
 MANAGER_ID NUMBER(6,0),
 DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4,0)
 )
```

I can't figure the problem out, can anyone help?

Comment: you should [drop if exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799128/oracle-if-table-exists), also i think you need to remove the `;` from the end of `CREATE TABLE deleted_employees;`

Comment: @marc_s, it's acceptable to specify the length of a VARCHAR2 in bytes or chars - you can choose. The default is typically bytes.

Answer (score 4):

The first error, ORA-00942, is because the table doesn't exist the first time you run this; you're probably expecing that, but it's a bit ugly.

The second is because you have a stray semicolon at the end of the first line of the create statement. The error message isn't entirely helpful but does actually say what is wrong. The rest are knock-ons from that, as it tries to interpret the rest of the command, and can't...

```
CREATE TABLE deleted_employees
(
 EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(6,0),
 FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
 LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
 EMAIL VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
 PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) , 
 HIRE_DATE DATE , 
 JOB_ID VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
 SALARY NUMBER(8,2),
 COMMISSION_ID NUMBER(2,2),
 MANAGER_ID NUMBER(6,0),
 DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4,0)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ; from your create table query.

I have shown this in sqlfiddle: click here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a57e9/1