# PL/SQL if table not exist create

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hello i use oracle SQL developer

I have create a procedure, and i need to check if a table exist, if not exist i must create how can do?

I have try this

```
DECLARE v_emp int:=0;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) into v_emp FROM dba_tables; 

  if v_emp = 0 then
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table EMPLOYEE ( ID NUMBER(3), NAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL)';
  end if;
END;
```

but give me an error 00103 because not find table

Comment: Please provide your example code.

Comment: See my answer. Try to query `all_tables` not just ´dba_tables`.

Comment: Instead of `DBA_TABLES` you could try `USER_TABLES`.

Comment: What is the reason for writing this code? Is it a homework question? Typically, you wouldn't do this in production code, as tables are permanent objects, and shouldn't be created on the fly (there are exceptions, but these are, IME, rare). If you need a table to house data only visible to that session, you would create a Global Temporary Table (GTT) and then refer to that in your code - you wouldn't create/drop tables on the fly.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799128/oracle-if-table-exists) maybe helps.

Comment: No when i launch my procedure, it show me tabel not found

Comment: error is ORA-00942 table or view not exist

Answer (score 4):

Just execute the create and watch the exception if thrown. Oracle would never replace the `DDL` of a table.

```
declare
  error_code NUMBER;
begin
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(AGE INT)';
exception
when others then
error_code := SQLCODE;
 if(error_code = -955)
 then
   dbms_output.put_line('Table exists already!'); 
 else
   dbms_output.put_line('Unknown error : '||SQLERRM); 
 end if;
end;
```

Comment: i don't know why when I put into procedure not run

Comment: did you enable `DBMS_OUTPUT` on ? `SET SERVERPUT ON` in `SQL*Plus`

Comment: ok in that case, Choose `View -> dbms output `- > And then click the `+` icon on the tab..

Comment: the compiler give me error ORA-00942 table or view not exist, because i delete the table. I need to create if not exist

Comment: I must insert into a procedure was first do a select, i click on compile but show me ORA-00942 table or view not exist

Comment: you are selecting `dba_tables` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82482/discussion-between-maheswaran-ravisankar-and-v3ctor).

Answer (score 2):

You can run this for example:

```
if (select count(*) from all_tables where table_name = 'yourTable')>0 then
-- table exists
else
-- table doesn't exist
end if;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try following,

```
declare
nCount NUMBER;
v_sql LONG;

begin
SELECT count(*) into nCount FROM dba_tables where table_name = 'EMPLOYEE';
IF(nCount <= 0)
THEN
v_sql:='
create table EMPLOYEE
(
ID NUMBER(3),
NAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
)';
execute immediate v_sql;

END IF;
end;
```