# Delete rows only if the table exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to run a delete statement on my database if a table was previously created.

The problem is - I can't just run the delete statement, since the product is not on every client's productive environments - therefore, they don't have the table where I want to run the delete statement, and would end up with an error `00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"`.

An example:

I would like to run something like this:

```
IF EXISTS (TABLE TB_FIELD)
    DELETE FROM TB_FIELD WHERE ID = '213';
```

If there isn't a generic statement, I would like one that would run for Oracle databases

Comment: Are you using SAP Hana or Oracle? Those are two **very** different database systems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle: If Table Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799128/oracle-if-table-exists)

Comment: I'm using both, depending on the client, @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one for Oracle.  This assumes the current user owns the table.  If you're updating someone else's table you'll need to swap out user_tables with dba_tables.

```
declare
    table_name_l    user_tables.table_name%type;
begin
    select table_name into table_name_l from user_tables where table_name = 'TB_FIELD';
    -- if we didn't raise an exception the table must exist 
    execute immediate 'delete from tb_field where id = :1' using '213';

    exception 
        when no_data_found then 
            -- do nothing - table doesn't exist
            null;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to catch and ignore the "table not found" exception:

```
declare
  l_id number := 12345;
begin
  execute immediate 'delete tb_field where id=:1' using l_id;
exception
  when others then
    if sqlcode != -942 /*table or view does not exist*/ then
      raise;
    end if;
end;
/
```