# any idea why this simple oracle sql query wont work? Create table add table and show table in one query

Tags: oracle

Do you have any idea why this won't work?

I want to create a table then add items to it and display it. It should be simple but every time I try I get a crash or an error.

```sql
CREATE TABLE test 
(a varchar(255),
    b varchar(255),
    c varchar(255),
    d varchar(255)
);
insert into test
(a,b,c,d)
Values
('dd','tt','te','rt');
select * from test
```

Comment: what tool are you using that crashes?  what are the errors?  Worked for me in Toad against Oracle 19c.  Although you should use VARCHAR2.

Comment: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 11 Column: 15

Comment: It all works [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oxrRB5wj)

Comment: It's most likely permissions then.  Preface the table name with your schema like `ian.test`

Comment: then the second time i run it i get,  Table TEST created. but no data is putin

Comment: then the third time Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE test 
(a varchar(2),
    b varchar(2),
    c varchar(2),
    d varchar(2)
)
Error report -
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @Ian the third time, the table is still there from prior runs, so the CREATE table is unnecessary.  You can destroy and re-create it each time by starting your script with this: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ian.TEST`; (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799128/oracle-if-table-exists)

Comment: if you prefaced your table with a schema as Gary_W suggested, then you need to do the same with your insert, as in INSERT INTO IAN.TEST(...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the system cant keep up with me creating it seems to be more a permissions/server side thing :)