# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist - Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-data-jpa

I've got a spring project with the following application.yaml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: phonebook
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
        format_sql: true
      show-sql: true

  # Datasource Configuration
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/freepdb1
    username: username
    password: topsecret
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    type: oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource
    oracleucp:
      connection-factory-class-name: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
      sql-for-validate-connection: select * from dual
      connection-pool-name: phoneBookConnectionPool
      initial-pool-size: 15
      min-pool-size: 10
      max-pool-size: 30
      fast-connection-failover-enabled: false
```

To initialize the database I've created a `schema.sql` file with the following content:

```
DROP TABLE PHONEBOOK PURGE;

CREATE TABLE PHONEBOOK (
    "PHONEBOOK_ID" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( START WITH 1 CACHE 20 ) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "FIRST_NAME"   VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
    "LAST_NAME"    VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
    "PHONE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
    "CREATE_DATE"  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSDATE,
    PRIMARY KEY ("PHONEBOOK_ID")
);
```

And a `data.sql` file with this content:

```
INSERT INTO PHONEBOOK (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER) VALUES ('James', 'Butt', '504-621-8927');
INSERT INTO PHONEBOOK (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER) VALUES ('Josephine', 'Darakjy', '810-292-9388');
INSERT INTO PHONEBOOK (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER) VALUES ('Art', 'Venere', '856-636-8749');
INSERT INTO PHONEBOOK (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER) VALUES ('Lenna', 'Paprocki', '907-385-4412');
INSERT INTO PHONEBOOK (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER) VALUES ('Donette', 'Foller', '513-570-1893');
INSERT INTO PHONEBOOK (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER) VALUES ('Simona', 'Morasca', '419-503-2484');
```

`schema.sql` and `data.sql` lives under the `resources` directory in my project. However when I run the application it stops with the following error:

```
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Which makes total sense as the table doesn't exist. Is there a way of configuring Spring so the application doesn't quit and just ignores the error and creates the table and moves on?

I'm using Oracle 19c and Spring 2.7.10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle: If Table Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799128/oracle-if-table-exists)

Comment: If you are using Oracle 23c: then you can use If Table Exists clause "drop   table IF  EXIST PHONEBOOK; " , or else you can check if the table is present in ALL_TABLES and then Drop it.

Comment: I tried the  `WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE NONE DROP TABLE PHONEBOOK PURGE;` statement but it gives `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`

Comment: Found the solution, I needed to add `sql.init.continue-on-error: true`

Answer (score 0):

sql:
init:
mode: always
continue-on-error: true