# I Can't Create a Script on Apex Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

So, I'm a university student and I'm new to SQL. Our professor gave us a team project that requires creating a script file on Oracle Apex (iacademy2.oracle.com on web complier). My friends and I tried our best, but Oracle always gives a lot of errors when we try to run it.
Here is the code and error log:
(Drop table and modify tables also required, we know they're unneccesery)

```
-- Drop all tables if they exist
DROP TABLE Authors;
DROP TABLE Publishers;
DROP TABLE BookCategories;
DROP TABLE BookTypes;
DROP TABLE Members;
DROP TABLE Students;
DROP TABLE Teachers;
DROP TABLE Books;
DROP TABLE Rentals;
DROP TABLE Penalties;

-- Authors
CREATE TABLE "Authors" (
    "AuthorID" NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    "AuthorName" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
);

-- Publishers
CREATE TABLE "Publishers" (
    "PublisherID" NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    "PublisherName" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
);

-- Book Categories
CREATE TABLE "BookCategories" (
    "CategoryID" NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    "CategoryName" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);

-- Book Types
CREATE TABLE "BookTypes" (
    "BookTypeID" NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    "BookTypeName" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);

-- Members
CREATE TABLE "Members" (
    "MemberID" NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    "FirstName" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    "MiddleName" VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL,
    "LastName" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    "BookLimit" NUMBER CHECK ("BookLimit" >= 1 AND "BookLimit" <= 5) NOT NULL,
    "DonationHistory" VARCHAR2(255),
    "PenaltyStatus" NUMBER NOT NULL,
    "MembershipNumber" NUMBER NOT NULL,
    "StudentNumber" NUMBER,
    "TeacherNumber" NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_StudentNumber" FOREIGN KEY ("StudentNumber") REFERENCES "Students"("StudentNumber"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_TeacherNumber" FOREIGN KEY ("TeacherNumber") REFERENCES "Teachers"("TeacherNumber")
);

-- Students
CREATE TABLE "Students" (
    "StudentNumber" NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    "Department" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
);

-- Teachers
CREATE TABLE "Teachers" (
    "TeacherNumber" NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    "Age" NUMBER NOT NULL
);

-- Books
CREATE TABLE "Books" (
    "BookID" NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    "Title" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
    "PublisherID" NUMBER,
    "AuthorID" NUMBER,
    "CategoryID" NUMBER,
    "BookTypeID" NUMBER,
    "ISBN" VARCHAR2(13) UNIQUE,
    "PublicationYear" NUMBER,
    "PrintDate" DATE,
    "BarcodeNumber" VARCHAR2(20) UNIQUE,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_PublisherID" FOREIGN KEY ("PublisherID") REFERENCES "Publishers"("PublisherID"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_AuthorID" FOREIGN KEY ("AuthorID") REFERENCES "Authors"("AuthorID"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_CategoryID" FOREIGN KEY ("CategoryID") REFERENCES "BookCategories"("CategoryID"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_BookTypeID" FOREIGN KEY ("BookTypeID") REFERENCES "BookTypes"("BookTypeID")
);

-- Rentals
CREATE TABLE "Rentals" (
    "RentalID" NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    "BookID" NUMBER,
    "MemberID" NUMBER,
    "RentalDate" DATE,
    "ReturnDate" DATE,
    "RentalNumber" NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_BookID" FOREIGN KEY ("BookID") REFERENCES "Books"("BookID"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_MemberID" FOREIGN KEY ("MemberID") REFERENCES "Members"("MemberID")
);

-- Penalty Records
CREATE TABLE "Penalties" (
    "PenaltyID" NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    "RentalID" NUMBER,
    "PenaltyAmount" NUMBER(10, 2),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_RentalID" FOREIGN KEY ("RentalID") REFERENCES "Rentals"("RentalID")
);

-- Modifications

-- FOREIGN KEY modifications
ALTER TABLE "Members" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_StudentNumber";
ALTER TABLE "Members" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_TeacherNumber";

-- FOREIGN KEY modifications
ALTER TABLE "Members" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_StudentNumber" FOREIGN KEY ("StudentNumber") REFERENCES "Students"("StudentNumber");
ALTER TABLE "Members" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_TeacherNumber" FOREIGN KEY ("TeacherNumber") REFERENCES "Teachers"("TeacherNumber");

-- Unique Constraints
ALTER TABLE "Books" ADD CONSTRAINT "UQ_ISBN" UNIQUE ("ISBN");
ALTER TABLE "Books" ADD CONSTRAINT "UQ_BarcodeNumber" UNIQUE ("BarcodeNumber");

-- Modify PenaltyAmount to INTEGER
--ALTER TABLE "Penalties" MODIFY PenaltyAmount NUMBER(12, 2);

-- Drop and Add FOREIGN KEY constraint in Penalties
ALTER TABLE "Penalties" DROP CONSTRAINT "FK_RentalID";

ALTER TABLE "Penalties" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_RentalID" FOREIGN KEY ("RentalID") REFERENCES "Rentals"("RentalID");

-- Drop and Recreate the Members table
DROP TABLE "Members";

CREATE TABLE "Members" (
    "MemberID" NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    "FirstName" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    "LastName" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    "BookLimit" NUMBER CHECK ("BookLimit" >= 1 AND "BookLimit" <= 5) NOT NULL,
    "DonationHistory" VARCHAR2(255),
    "PenaltyStatus" NUMBER(1, 0) NOT NULL,
    "MembershipNumber" NUMBER NOT NULL,
    "StudentNumber" NUMBER,
    "TeacherNumber" NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_StudentNumber" FOREIGN KEY ("StudentNumber") REFERENCES "Students"("StudentNumber"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_TeacherNumber" FOREIGN KEY ("TeacherNumber") REFERENCES "Teachers"("TeacherNumber")
);

-- Data

-- Authors
INSERT INTO "Authors" ("AuthorID", "AuthorName")
VALUES
    (1, 'Emrah Safa Gürkan'),
    (2, 'Namık Kemal'),
    (3, 'Christy Brown');

-- Publishers
INSERT INTO "Publishers" ("PublisherID", "PublisherName")
VALUES
    (1, 'Sky Publishing'),
    (2, 'Ephesus Publications'),
    (3, 'Red Cat Publishing');

-- Book Categories
INSERT INTO "BookCategories" ("CategoryID", "CategoryName")
VALUES
    (1, 'History'),
    (2, 'Literature'),
    (3, 'Poetry');

-- Book Types
INSERT INTO "BookTypes" ("BookTypeID", "BookTypeName")
VALUES
    (1, 'Physical Book'),
    (2, 'E-book'),
    (3, 'Audiobook');

-- Students
INSERT INTO "Students" ("StudentNumber", "Department")
VALUES
    (101, 'IT'),
    (102, 'BTBS'),
    (103, 'BTEP');

-- Teachers
INSERT INTO "Teachers" ("TeacherNumber", "Age")
VALUES
    (201, 34),
    (202, 43),
    (203, 68);

-- Members
INSERT INTO "Members" ("MemberID", "FirstName", "LastName", "BookLimit", "PenaltyStatus", "MembershipNumber", "StudentNumber")
VALUES
    (1, 'Mehmet', 'Akif', 3, 0, 1001, 101),
    (2, 'Sezer', 'Yazıcı', 5, 1, 1002, NULL),
    (3, 'Nilgün', 'Çarıkçı', 2, 0, 1003, 103);

-- Books
INSERT INTO "Books" ("BookID", "Title", "PublisherID", "AuthorID", "CategoryID", "BookTypeID", "ISBN", "PublicationYear", "PrintDate", "BarcodeNumber")
VALUES
    (1, 'Clouds', 1, 1, 1, 1, '1234567890123', 1978, TO_DATE('1978-02-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'B12345'),
    (2, 'Book2', 2, 2, 2, 2, '2345678901234', 2022, TO_DATE('2022-02-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'B67890'),
    (3, 'Book3', 3, 3, 3, 3, '3456789012345', 2006, TO_DATE('2006-03-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'B98765');

-- Rentals
INSERT INTO "Rentals" ("RentalID", "BookID", "MemberID", "RentalDate", "ReturnDate", "RentalNumber")
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, TO_DATE('2023-11-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2023-12-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 101),
    (2, 2, 2, TO_DATE('2023-11-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2023-15-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 102),
    (3, 3, 3, TO_DATE('2023-12-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2023-16-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 103);

-- Penalties
INSERT INTO "Penalties" ("PenaltyID", "RentalID", "PenaltyAmount")
VALUES
    (1, 1, 0.00),   -- No penalty for Member 1
    (2, 2, 5.00),   -- Member 2 penalized with 5 ₺
    (3, 3, 0.00);   -- Member 3 did not receive a penalty
```

Also, I added eror log as images

**Error Log 1**
[image: Error Log 1]

**Error Log 2**
[image: Error Log 2]

Comment: start by looking at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799128/oracle-if-table-exists

Answer (score 4):

Multiple things that are causing errors:

1. Quoted identifiers [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-3C59E44A-5140-4BCA-B9E1-3039C8050C49).

`"Authors"` and `Authors` is not the same. You're dropping `Authors`: no quotes which means Oracle will store this as `AUTHORS` and it can be referenced without quotes case insensitive or as `"AUTHORS"`. You're creating `"Authors"` which can only be referenced as `"Authors"`. So the drop statement will not drop the tables.

**Rule**: do not mix quoted and unquoted identifiers.

**Best practice**: do not quote identifiers - it causes headaches.

2. Invalid insert syntax. The syntax

```
INSERT INTO "Authors" ("AuthorID", "AuthorName")
VALUES
    (1, 'Emrah Safa Gürkan'),
    (2, 'Namık Kemal'),
    (3, 'Christy Brown');
```

is only supported from 23c onwards. Currently apex.oracle.com is still on 19c. Use one insert statement per record.

```
INSERT INTO Authors (AuthorID, AuthorName)
VALUES    (1, 'Emrah Safa Gürkan');
INSERT INTO Authors (AuthorID, AuthorName)
VALUES        (2, 'Namık Kemal');
INSERT INTO Authors (AuthorID, AuthorName)
VALUES        (3, 'Christy Brown');
```

3. Dropping table referenced by foreign keys:
   Use the `DROP TABLE CASCADE CONSTRAINT` directive.

As a rule of thumb, for large scripts... start with a single command, run, fix any errors, add more statements, rinse & repeat. That way you'll run into a single error that is easy to diagnose & fix. Creating a large script can lead to many errors that are connected and hard to fix.